# JQuery not working after using append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, delegates, append, live

I have a button that has the .append() function. So every time I click on that button, it adds 1 new DIV element to the body.

But the DIV elements have the fadeIn() function. That means every time I add a new DIV element, it should fade in slowly, but it doesn't.

```
<button id="btn1">CLICK</button>
<div class="box"></div>
```

[HERE IS THE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j2j87v4f/)

I have found some similar problems here but none of them really helped me so I would be very glad if someone gave me a decent solution.

Comment: Please post the code here, not just link to an external site.

Comment: The issue is you are attaching fadein before the html exists.  So in jquery, when you add the new html it doesn't have the fadein attached.  The jquery documentation shows proper usage: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: Ah that is good to know, thanks. And how do I generally add elements and attach them to the functions? If I knew this, my problem would be solved.

Answer (score 2):

you can try something like this

```
$('#btn1').on('click',function(){
    $("body").append(
        $(document.createElement('div'))
            .addClass('box')
            .fadeIn(3000)
    );
});
```

Fiddle demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j2j87v4f/6/)